# element not clickable and how to check mandatory fields

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
 `i have "Add Driver" feature in that so many fields are there all are 
   mandatory..if i will not enter any data into fields ,it will display 
   "field is required message",,for this how can i write selenium script`.

     WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
     wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Add Driver')]"))).click();
```

`[below picture is an example,,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmxLL.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmxLL.png)

```
i didn't get how to write logic i m new selenium help me..
```

Comment: for that xpath i m getting   " org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException:"  this exception

Comment: anybody help me